# What is the best sorting algorithm in this situation?

Tags: c++, sorting

```
myarray = empty
n = 10000
range = 1000
loop 1 to n {
    x = random number between 1 and range 
    if x not in myarray {
        add x to myarray
        sort myarray
        do something 
    }
}
```

I considered insertion sort, but that would require elements to shift. And quicksort would be bad on already sorted lists. The best I could think of now is a Min Heap. Is there some lesser known sorting algorithm that's better for this situation? Is it in C++'s STL?

Comment: most quicksort implementations are fast on already sorted lists.  The std::sort is designed for roughly evenly distributed data, just how you have it.

Comment: Why do you even sort here ? The situation doesn't require the repeated sorting. You are going to add element, if its not present and just sort it after that loop.

Comment: @King my mistake, I will add a do something line, so I will need to sort it after each iteration.

Comment: I this situation, what about filling a vector with all the values, shuffling it and then picking the first 1000?

Comment: Mark's answer below is the best one. Another thing is unless you perform a search operation after every insert, I won't recommend this approach of looping. Even in such case, I recommend you to restructure your code , if possible. Please re-think your programming flow and structure. In the worst case, you can continue. Mark's answer just works for you in this scenario.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for `std::set`. It keeps things sorted as you insert, and gives you a quick "not in" operation.

Answer (score 3):

The **very best option** when you know that the numbers you're sorting will always be between `0` and a `max_value` is [**Counting sort**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort), with an unsurpassable complexity: `O(n)`.

Comment: or even for small ranges bool contains_element[range], contains_element[ixd] is true if idx is in myarray

Answer (score 2):

The best option would be to not sort the array at all and then wait until the end before sorting.  Sorting repeatedly in an array will be expensive, because you will have to shift elements over one way or the other.

Since you are interested in the operations

- Insert an element
- Check if an element is there
- Maintain sorted order

You should consider looking into a different structure than an array, perhaps a binary search tree, which supports fast (O(log n)) insertion and can be used to retrieve the sorted order.

Hope this helps!